# webpack tutorial doesn't work, error require .css file

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack 2.2.1

On this page https://webpack.github.io/docs/tutorials/getting-started/

this line:

```
require("./style.css");
```

produces this error:

```
ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style' in '/Users/mkm/www/webpack'
```

I assume you can't "require" css. What is supposed to be here?

Thx
Mike

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in your question, just scroll down the page a little...

"We want to add a CSS file to our application.

webpack can only handle JavaScript natively, so we need the css-loader to process CSS files. We also need the style-loader to apply the styles in the CSS file.

Run npm install css-loader style-loader to install the loaders."

```
require("./style.css");
```

is a php instruction for your server to look for the .css file that adds the style to your content. The error is that the file isn't there, because you haven't installed it.

Comment: Ah yes. Thanks. But now I get ERROR in ./entry.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style' in '/Users/mkm/www/webpack'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.
                 You need to specify 'style-loader' instead of 'style'.
 @ ./entry.js 1:0-22

Comment: Did you follow all the preceding steps in order and get the output it says you should see?

Comment: Got it, have to rename style.css to style-loader.css and in webconfig change style,css to style-loader, css-loader

Comment: There you go... sounds like you're on your way!